# Sorting DataGridView ComboBox Values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

i've been trying to sort out some values that i currently add to the comboboxcell through a loop and i use the sort with the dataview however this is only sorting through the 1 number of the value and not taking into consideration the rest of the numbers.

Sample code:

[image: 1]

Result:

[image: 2]

What i'm trying to obtain is the following example: 1, 10, 100, 200, instead of, 1, 11, 110, 2, 20, 23, 3 and so forth. If anyone got any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You need to sort by value. Instead, your program is ordering alphabetically.

Comment: @Zeokat How would you go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ to sort it and get the "MATERIALPROFILE" list.

Here is a simple demo that setting combobox data dousrce.

```
List<decimal> datasource = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .OrderBy(r => r.Field<decimal>("MATERIALPROFILE"))
    .Select(r => r.Field<decimal>("MATERIALPROFILE"))
    .ToList();


DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
combo.DataSource = datasource;

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);
```

---

**Update:**

Modify OrderBy clause, like:

```
.OrderBy(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("FieldName").Split('x')[0].Trim()))
```

Comment: Error i'm getting:
https://prnt.sc/wfu4ml

Code Sample:
https://prnt.sc/wfu522

Comment: @StevenLemos What is the type of "MATERIALPROFILE"? In my test, it's a "decimal". You can modify it to the type you set

Comment: So i've store these as string as there's an (x) seperating some of these "MATERIALPROFILE". So i could have decimal numbers just like the ones on the screenshot but i could also have something alike this https://prnt.sc/wgkr4i

I have changed it from decimal to string, however, i need it to take the first 2 numbers of every string and use those to sort it.

Comment: @StevenLemos First 2 numbers? Sort it like `120,150,180,20,200,...`?

Comment: Sorry, meant to say the whole number prior to the (x) separating them.

So for example:
10 x 10 //
14 x 14 //
20 x 20 //
60 x 60 //
100 x 100 //
200 x 200 //
300 x 300 

And so on

Comment: @StevenLemos Have updated the answer, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ:

```
DataTable sortedByValue = sortedDT.AsEnumerable()
                   .OrderBy(r=> r.Field<decimal>("MATERIALPROFILE"))
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Tried using it too but i get the same result(error) as the answer above.